# What happens when String args[] is replaced with int args[] in Java?

Tags: java

What happens when the argument of the main function

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

is replaced with

```
public static void main(int args[])
```

and one tries to run it?

Comment: What do you mean by result? Your java program will run but it won't have any starting point without the ```public static void main(String args[])```

Comment: means its complie but why not it is execute

Comment: easiest is just to try and see...

Answer (score 4):

It won't execute since that's what the language's designers decided. [Section 12.1.4 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4) specifies how exactly the main method's signature should be defined.

> The method main must be declared public, static, and void. It must specify a formal parameter whose declared type is array of String. Therefore, either of the following declarations is acceptable:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

And

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

Also `static` and `void` keywords can be interchanged.

That is why changing the parameters to int will just make that `main` method as a normal Java method. So it means that your Java application doesn't have any starting point, the standard `main` method.

Answer (score 3):

your Program will never run if you change your method `public static void main(String args[])` to `public static void main(int args[])` but it compiles successfully.

`public static void main(String args[])` basically a initial or entry point. If you write  `public static void main(String args[])` along with `public static void main(String args[])` then it is the overloaded function of `main`. Compiler always looking for `public static void main(String args[])` for starting the program. If this method not found then at run time program gives you a error.

That's why the signature of the method is always:

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

This is the access modifier of the main method. It has to be public so that java runtime can execute this method. Remember that if you make any method non-public then it’s not allowed to be executed by any program, there are some access restrictions applied. So it means that the main method has to be public